# Large scrolling div unusable on ipad

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, mobile-safari

I am developing a web based mobile site which has two views, one of these views is a list view of data. The data is filtered based on user input. The issue is that the list could potentially have 3000 items in it. When that is the case scrolling is super slow. However when the list is filtered to about 100 elements it is very snappy. Are there any other approaches which can be taken to handle this amount of data within a browser on an ipad, it seems to be hitting some memory limit..

code for the scrolling container

```
div style="display:none;" id="list-view" class="list-view">
    <div id="list-view-container">
        <div id="list-header" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 med">
                property ID
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                property Name
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 wide">
                Address
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                Project Status
            </div>

        </div>
        <hr>

    <div id="list-view-container-inner">
       // ~3000 divs here
</div>
```

How I make this div scrollable

```
  function touchScroll(id){
        try{
            var el=document.getElementById(id);
            var scrollStartPos=0;

            document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
                scrollStartPos=this.scrollTop+event.touches[0].pageY;
                event.preventDefault();

            },false);

            document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
                this.scrollTop=scrollStartPos-event.touches[0].pageY;
                event.preventDefault();
            },false);
        }catch(err){
            //throw some errors
        }
    }


$(function() {
     touchScroll('list-view-container-inner');
});
```

The only "solution" I have is to require the user to filter down the data more.

Comment: If the div should overflow, wouldn't it be better to set a static height on the div, and then set `overflow: auto` on the element?

Comment: ^Agree. And to expand on what @SebastianJobBjørnagerJensen said, add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to accelerate the layer (among other benefits). Any reason you need to use TouchEvents to handle scrolling?

Comment: The page has google maps elements which seems to be breaking the -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;.